# Use JFrame instead of JDialog in Netbeans Wizard

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, wizard

I have build an application using the Netbeans Wizard Framework as outlined [here](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-wizard.html) and [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/28/using-wizard-api.html).  I have my application working properly, but the problem I have is that the application does not show in the windows taskbar.  I am pretty sure the problem is that the Wizard Framework uses a JDialog instead of a JFrame, but I can't figure out if that can be changed.

If anyone has experience with this framework, please let me know if it can be made to appear in the taskbar.

Comment: Although the tools that generate graphical interfaces can save many lines of code are not always the best option, especially when you need to customize something. I'm not against that these are used, only that have not improved so much in Java. In .NET is another story.

Answer (score 4):

Changing is quite easy.

- Open the form in NetBeans.
- Change `extends javax.swing.JDialog` to `extends javax.swing.JFrame`.
- Save the file and close it.
- Reopen the file.
- In designer mode, make a change. I usually just change the name of a component.
- Save the file.
- Undo the change and save the file again.

You should be all set.

Comment: You will probably have to tweak the constructor (the default has the modal boolean for JDialog). You might also want to create a new JFrame form and copy the `public static void main(String[])` method that it uses to launch the JFrame, and then delete your generated class.

Comment: Define "the form" please. I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: NetBeans refers to graphically editable GUIs as "forms" because they consist of a .java file and a .form file which is an xml description of the GUI. When you open a form, you will see a Source/Design toggle in the upper left of the edit window.

Answer (score 1):

> Wizard Framework uses a JDialog instead of a JFrame, but I can't figure out if that can be changed.

- don't use more than one `JFrames`, this's road to the hell, you cann't to `setToFront`, `setOwner`, `iconify`, etc ...
- use `JDialog` or `JWindow` instead with parent to the one single `JFrame`
- use undecorated `JDialog`, with `setModal()` or is possible to set various `ModalityTypes` too

> If anyone has experience with this framework, please let me know if it can be made to appear in the taskbar.

- this `Swing Framework` is long time depreciated
- you can use [SplashScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) repeatly instead of `JDialog/JWindow`